# SQL query not running in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dataframe

I have the following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import mysql.connector

# Give the location of the file
loc = ("C:\\Users\\27826\\Desktop\\11Sixteen\\Models and Reports\\Historical results files\\EPL 1993-94.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(loc)

# Remove empty columns then rows
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

# Create DataFrame and then import to db (new game results table)
engine = create_engine("mysql://root:xxx@localhost/11sixteen")
df.to_sql('new_game_results', con=engine, if_exists="replace")

# Move from new games results table to game results table
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                             user="root",
                             passwd="xxx",
                             database="11sixteen")
my_cursor = db.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 11sixteen.game_results "
                  "SELECT * FROM 11sixteen.new_game_results WHERE "
                        "NOT EXISTS (SELECT date, HomeTeam "
                                    "FROM 11sixteen.game_results WHERE "
                                            "11sixteen.game_results.date = 11sixteen.new_game_results.date AND "
                                            "11sixteen.game_results.HomeTeam = 11sixteen.new_game_results.HomeTeam)")

print("complete")
```

Basically the objective is that I copy data from several excel files to a SQL table (one at a time) and then transfer it from there to the fuller table where ALL the data will be aggregated (without duplicates hopefully)

Everything works 100% except the SQL query as below:

```
INSERT INTO 11sixteen.game_results 
SELECT * FROM 11sixteen.new_game_results 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT date, HomeTeam 
                    FROM 11sixteen.game_results WHERE 
                                11sixteen.game_results.date = 11sixteen.new_game_results.date AND 
                                11sixteen.game_results.HomeTeam = 11sixteen.new_game_results.HomeTeam)
```

If I run the same query on MySQL Workbench it works perfect. Any ideas why I can't get Python to execute the query as expected?

Comment: what is not working ? you have any output ? an error message maybe ? if we do not know what is wrong, we cannot help.

Comment: @Steven no errors at all - the first table created is 100%, but it just does not copy the data to the fuller table - the code completes as the "complete" print line at the end of the code executes

Comment: then, you just need to add a commit.

Comment: DOH! Yes - I am a dumbass - thanks!

Comment: You can probably accept the answer then ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a commit at the end.

```py
db.commit()
```